# How to make a flare

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers, particles

I am trying to make a flare in blender (Not a lens flare) that I can then import into Unreal 4. I am new to blender, and cannot find any tutorials for this. Please give me some advice or guidance on how to start. I have a feeling that I will have to use particle systems and modifiers.

Comment: I think I would be helpful if you add a picture of what you're trying to create and maybe what you have already tried.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about something like a road flare, you actually cannot do this in Blender (for use in Unreal 4, anyway).  You can model the physical flare object in Blender, but the burning effect will be a combination of shaders and particle effects that run in Unreal 4 itself.

See:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Rendering/ParticleSystems